# Can anyone identify this beetle?

Tags: species-identification, entomology

[image: fruit chafer]

Fruit Chafer found in Zambezi valley at Victoria Falls on the Zambia/Zimbabwe border

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is a flower beetle in the family Scarabaeidae, subfamily Cetoniinae.
Derby's flower beetle (*Dicronorrhina derbyana*)
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dicronorrhina_derbyana